# Lower Back fat (can't lose it)

Tags: body-fat

I want to ask you a question about my waist size. It's been about 87.5 cm (34.25 inches) for a few weeks now and there is still a lot of fat around my lower back and lower abs but despite eating at a deficit i cant lose these inches. I have also been eating at a deficit for about a year now because i used to weigh 90kg so i don't know if this may have something to do with it. I have recently started bulking in hopes to gain more muscle so i can boost my metabolism but I don't want to get even fatter. I also realize that bulking will not help me lose fat as i will be in a calorie surplus but if i keep on cutting then i will be extremely skinny. I have good definition in my abs and chest etc. but it is this lower back/ab fat that wont go during my cut. I'm not sure if this could be due to insulin resistance or other factors but i have been doing intermittent fasting to try to make myself more insulin sensitive. I want to get to a 80 cm (31.5 inch) waist but it seems impossible as my waist wont go down in size.

Since bulking for the past 2 months I have gained about 5kg and went from 65KG to 70KG and my waist is now at 88.5CM, and the size of my arms and chest has also gone up. I want to have a narrower waist as the holidays are coming up and i want to look good when i go to the beach and take my top off but i don't know if cutting will mean that i lose my muscle. I fear that i will start to cut and lose muscle but no fat whatsoever and i will remain with a large waistline and the same amount of muscle i started the bulk with.

These are my stats:

Height:178CM (5'10")
Weight:70KG(154 lbs)
Age:17
Chest:105CM (41.3")

Thank you so much your time and help and sorry for the long read

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you bulk you also gain fat, when you cut you also lose muscle the question simply is what is the majority. Your goal in a cut is to lose mostly fat and vice versa in a bulk.
There is no way to avoid this. With proper training and eating you can guide your bulk or cut in the direction you would like it to go

If you decide to cut now you will definitely lose a bit of muscle ,however if your protein intake is adequate and you are lifting weights ,it will be minimal.
Many people store fat in various different areas , this is not controllable. The bottom line is, if you continue eating in a deficit you will lose it ,it will simply be a question of how lean do you personally need to be in order to lose it
Some people will see abs at 15% body fat some will require to be of lesser percent it has a lot to do with the shape of your muscles,skeletal structure, and where you store fat